# "John Brown has died" - why is this tense used?

Tags: grammar, tense, past-tense, expressions, present-tense

Whenever I see information about someone's recent death (usually well known, if this makes a difference), the expression used is

> John Doe has died.

Why is this tense used? What about the alternatives

- *John Doe died*.
- *John Doe is dead*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**has died** = a recent *fact*

**died** = an *event* from the past (maybe in chain of events or with details like date, cause of death, etc.)

**is dead** = John's contemporary *status* (he's not with us or just *found* dead)

Answer (score 1):

Because when famous people die, like John McCain, unless they say the  day or  hour or both, it just means it happened. If you say X died, you would have to say more.

By just saying: **x has died, that is enough for a headline.**

Otherwise, you would have to say: X died **this morning** in blah blah blah, for example.